Two questions on the instantaneous centre of rotation
In one of the "Additional solved problems" in chapter 6 of Analytical Mechanics, an Introduction (Fasano, Marmi, 2006) the following is stated:

Let $C(t)$ be the instantaneous centre of rotation. This is the point at time $t$ where the conjugate profiles are tangent. By definition, the velocity $v(C) = 0$ in the rigid motion (while in general the acceleration is not zero). Introduce the point $\bar{C}(t)$ (moving with respect to both the fixed and the body reference frame), which at every instant coincides with $C(t)$. In its absolute motion, $\bar{C}(t)$ travels over the fixed conjugate profile, while its trajectory in the relative motion is the body conjugate profile. It is easily seen that $\bar{C}(t)$ has equal absolute and relative velocities. Writing the absolute velocity field at every instant t in the form $$v(P) = ω × (P − \bar{C})$$ we obtain, by differentiating, the acceleration field $$a(P) = \dot{ω} × (P − \bar{C}) + ω × [ω × (P − \bar{C}) − \bar{v}]$$ where $\bar{v} = d\bar{C}/dt$.

I have the following questions:

What does it mean that "$\bar{C}(t)$ has equal absolute and relative velocities" and how we can prove it

Why, in the formula for $v(P)$, $\bar{v}$ does not appear, but it appears in the formula for $a(P)$? I suspect the catch lies in the definition $\bar{v} = d\bar{C}/dt$ which I wrongly assume same as $v(\bar{C})$. I understand that $v(C)=0$ by definition, but also that $v(\bar{C}) \neq v(C)$, but I can't see why $v(\bar{C})$ does not play a role in the formula for $v(P)$.



What do you mean by conjugate profiles?

@basics you can take this as the definition, as it is equivalent: Introduce the point $\bar{C}(t)$ (moving with respect to both the fixed and the body reference frame), which at every instant coincides with $C(t)$. In its absolute motion, $\bar{C}(t)$ travels over the fixed conjugate profile, while its trajectory in the relative motion is the body conjugate profile.

Both answers give a good insight, but for my own peace of mind I will attempt a rigorous answer myself, after a bit of reasoning.
I think the main point is considering $\bar{C}(t)$ as the locus of points, in the absolute frame or in the body frame respectively, that coincide with the istantaneous center of rotation $C$ at time $t$. As the quoted text says, the important thing to keep in mind is that $\bar{C}$ is moving with respect to both frames, hence it cannot be considered a fixed point in neither the absolute or the body frame.

How we can prove that $\bar{C}(t)$ has equal absolute and relative velocity?

We express the relative velocity of $\bar{C}(t_0)$ as $(\frac{dW}{dt})_R$ in the body frame with origin $O$ matching $\bar{C}(t_0)$ at $t_0$. We have that the absolute velocity is $\frac{dW}{dt}=(\frac{dW}{dt})_R+\omega(t) \times W=(\frac{dW}{dt})_R$ as the vector $W=\bar{C(t)}-O$ is zero for $t_0$.

Why, in the formula for $v(P)$, $\bar{v}$ does not appear, but it appears in the formula for $a(P)$?

The equation $$v(P,t) = \omega(t) × (P − \bar{C}(t))$$ holds for each $t$ and tells me that, at time $t$, the absolute speed of point $P$ (a fixed point of the body frame) is the vector product of the angular velocity $\omega$ at that time for the vector $(P-O)$: as the chosen pole $O$ (a fixed point in the body frame) happens to have zero instantaneous velocity at time $t$. $\bar{C}$ is moving, but cannot be considered a pole because it is not fixed in the body frame, so its velocity is not contributing to $v(t)$. Remind that the "full" formula for the absolute velocity is $v(P)=v(O)+\omega \times (P-O)$ when the pole $O$ is any point fixed in the body frame, whose absolute speed $v(O)$ can in general be non zero. Note the positive sign. Now, the fact that the equation holds for any times, allows two things. First, we can use the confusing notation $(P-\bar{C}(t))$ to express at each time the vector from the istantaneous centre of rotation to $P$; second, we can differentiate both sides of the equation, considering the following increment
$$v(P,t+\Delta) = \omega(t+\Delta) × (P − \bar{C}(t+\Delta))$$
This explains why $\bar{v}$ appears, with negative sign, in the formula for $a(t)$. It is not the "velocity of the pole" (which is zero) but the contribution of $\bar{C}$ to the derivative:
$$\frac{dv(P,t)}{dt} = \dot{\omega} \times (P - \bar{C}) + \omega(t) \times (\frac{dP}{dt} − \frac{d\bar{C}}{dt})= \dot{ω} × (P − \bar{C}) + ω × [ω × (P − \bar{C}) − \bar{v}]
$$


$~\vec C(t)~$ be the instantaneous center of rotation , this mean that
$$\dot{\vec{C}}(t)=\vec 0$$ you can obtain  the coordinates of $~\vec C~$ in the prime coordinate system, in this case $~\dot{\vec{C}}(t)~$ is the relative velocity ,or in initial system in this case $~\dot{\vec{C}}(t)~$ is the absolute velocity
Example : Ladder falling to the floor
point 1 till 8 are the trajectory of the the instantaneous center of rotation.


I do not understand this naming scheme
My theory is as follows:
I think it refers to the theorem that motion can always be decomposed into rotational and parallel translational. The article names the motion due to rotation as relative velocity and the motion due to translation, as absolute velocity.
You are correct that the velocity $\vec{v}_C$ of C should appear in the general expression of the velocity $\vec{v}_A$ of an arbitrary point A
$$ \vec{v}_A = \vec{\omega} \times ( \vec{r}_A - \vec{r}_C) + \vec{v}_C $$
But in the case where C lies on the axis of rotation, only parallel motion is allowed and $\vec{v}_C \propto \vec{\omega}$. This scalar factory between the two is often called the pitch $h$
$$ \vec{v}_A = \vec{\omega} \times ( \vec{r}_A - \vec{r}_C) + h \, \vec{\omega} \tag{1} $$
The above transforms the rotation geometry, described by $\vec{\omega}$, $\vec{r}_C$ and $h$ into a velocity field.
The reverse is always possible
$$ \begin{aligned}
   h & = \frac{ \vec{\omega} \cdot \vec{v}_A}{ \| \vec{\omega} \|^2} \\
  \vec{r}_C & = \vec{r}_A +  \frac{ \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}_A}{ \| \vec{\omega} \|^2}
\end{aligned}$$
